# Create a dictionary from a nested list

Tags: python

I am looking to convert the a list of 2-element lists to a dictionary. Note that I do *not* want to use *group_by* that has different outcomes than a simple conversion to *dict*.  Is this possible?  The two most obvious ways to try it out are not supported:

```
d = { x for x in [[1,2],[3,4]]}
```

Which gives us:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
d = { *x for x in [[1,2],[3,4]]}
```

Which results in :

> SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension

Comment: Expected output? Is `dict(my_list)` what you need?

Comment: `d = { x: y for x, y in [[1,2],[3,4]]}`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo  ya that's it - pls make answer

Comment: @DanielMesejo: but that is a dict comprehension, not a set comprehension

Comment: You should edit the title of the question.

Comment: @yatu trying `dict` out : yes that looks to be what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

`d = { x: y for x, y in [[1,2],[3,4]]}`

**Output**

```
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

As suggested by @DeepSpace you could do:

```
dict([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Comment: No need for the loop. Just do `dict([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`